# use of pointers in passing as an argument

Tags: c, pointers

I have few conceptual problem in understanding the code
Below are the description

```
char dest[100];
char *info;

Byte *ie;
```

Function declaration  says

```
getValue(Byte tag, Byte *msg, int len)
```

we pass something like

```
getValue(0X01, &info[4], 30);
```

here I understand that I am passing address of values to the pointer.

Now there is 2nd function

```
retriveValue( Byte *ie, Byte *digits, Byte totalLen)
```

in this function we pass something like

```
retriveValue(&ie[3], (Byte*)&dest, 2);
```

Here , I guess, we are converting char to pointer of type byte and passing Address to it.

Now my question is:

1. What is wrong if I convert dest to byte and pass address like `(Byte)&dest`?
2. How would I pass if dest is of type `char*` like for eg `char *dest;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
retriveValue(&ie[3], (Byte*)&dest, 2);
```

here in 2nd argument you have taken address of dest & then pointer cast it by (Byte*)

**1>What is wrong if I convert dest to byte and pass address like (Byte)&dest?**

by doing this you are casting the address of dest into Byte.(not Byte pointer)

**2>How would I pass if dest is of type char* like for eg char *dest;?**

then no need to add "&" just write

```
retriveValue(&ie[3], (Byte*)dest, 2);
```

Comment: It helped me to understand  things . Thanks a lot Mr 32.

Comment: Hi I got another doubt . while looking at some other code. There is function say addString( Byte tag, char *value); here we passed something like addstring( 32, (char*)rpAddr) where rpAddr is static Byte rpAddr[100];  if we apply above concept shouldnt it be (char*)&rpAddr?

Comment: there "char value" so u should pass (char)rpAddr...if there was "char * value" then u should pass (char*)&rpAddr..

Comment: why you unaccepted my answer? i have all ready answered all your question..!!

Answer (score 0):

"we pass something like"

```
getValue(0X01, &info[4], 30);
```

Oh do you now? Because that is scary amounts of bad karma being built up there.

First off, passing in hex values is a little weird. You could pass in a constant or a #defined value like TAG_01. In your application it may be perfectly fine, but I'd be wary.

The second argument is where it gets scary. info is a pointer (presumably set to &dest), the value that info holds is the address of the thing you're pointing to. If you wanted to pass in an address, you'd point into to the thing, and then pass in info, without the ampersand or treating it like an array. What you're doing using the square brackets [ ] to get an element of dest, and then getting address of that.

Now, it could be that you're using pointers in some ingenious way, and you really do want to reference the 4th byte after it. But I doubt it. You're probably just dinking around with pointers to see how they work, which is fine. But when you start to make stuff, if you want to pass in a message, declare a message and send that. Don't imbed a character string into part of a larger array. It's bad form. Use a struct instead.

> here I understand that I am passing address of values to the pointer.

Well, you're passing an address to a function, not a pointer.

"in this function we pass something like"

```
retriveValue(&ie[3], (Byte*)&dest, 2);
```

Again, I'm in a cold sweat over how scary wrong this is. Never do this. Who is this nefarious "we" you speak of? Are you part of some sort of horrible cult chanting an unspeakable dialect of C in an attempt to usher in a dark reign of Cthulu? Does h̡e͜͟ ͟c̀om͠e̴͝?̢̛͟

Anyway, cult aside,
**What is wrong if I convert dest to byte and pass address like (Byte)&dest?**

As Monsieur 32 pointed out, you're not passing an address if you do that, you're passing a Byte. Remember, that a Byte is 8 bits long. It's one char. An address is usually 32 or 64 bits, depending on the environment. So when you cast it like that, you're dropping 3/4ish of the data you need, and it doesn't fit the definition of the function. And it's a sin against nature.

**How would I pass if dest is of type char* like for eg char *dest;?**
Yep, just `dest`, all plain and vanilla by itself. This is because `dest` isn't a char. It's declared as `dest[100]`, which means `dest[0]` is a char, but dest is the address of `dest[0]`, like a pointer.

The array convention is really just a bit of molding over pointers to help keep things straight. There's no functional difference between `*(dest+3)` and `dest[3]`. On a technical level, arrays and pointer are different in that array declarations like `dest` would be treated as a `const` at compile time, so it wouldn't take up any RAM. A char* pointer would have it's own little hunk of RAM that you could increment while looping through your data, but only the eversleeping dark one uses pointers like that. Why is he sleeping? Endless loop because he didn't cast his pointers correctly.

Finally, if you already accepted Mr.32's answer, which was WAY ahead of mine, you really should put it back. And just say no to dead alien gods.

Comment: +1 for humor, -1 for the incorrect intArray pointer description in the second to last paragraph.

Comment: Dangit, I should have checked that. It's just *(intArray+3) still... Which confuses me a bit. Need to look over how arrays really store information again.